# How do I add or delete a node from the middle of a linked list?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to figure out how to delete a node in the middle of a linked list. Currently I am using **setitem** to add nodes to the front and end of the list and using **delitem** to delete a node from the front and end. I'm having trouble figuring out how I can use these two functions to add or delete nodes from the middle.

For example, to add, I know I need to traverse the linked list until the specified index and keep track of two nodes (previous and current).
Previous node points to the new node, and the new node points to the next node.

```
from utils import Node, Collections, StaticArray

class LinkedList(Collections):
    def __init__(self, isSet = False, isDoubly = False, isCircular = False):
        super(LinkedList,self).__init__()
        self.head=None
        self.isSet= isSet
        self.isDoubly=isDoubly
        self.isCircular=isCircular
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        count=0
        cur=self.head
        while True:
            if cur == None:
                break
                
            if count ==index:
                return cur 
            
            cur=cur.next
            count += 1
            
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=Node(value)
        elif index == 0: #adding a value in the front 
            node=Node(value)
            node.next=self.head   # node = E, self.head =A
            self.head=node #node=E -> self.head =A
            
            if self.isDoubly:
                self.head.prev=node
            self.head=node
            
            
        elif self[index]==None: #adding a value in the end 
            self[len(self)-1]
            cur.next=Node(value)
            if self.isCircular:
                cur.next.next=self.head
        
        #else add to middle 
    
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        if self.head==None:
            return
        elif index==0: #removing from the front 
            self.head=self.head.next
        elif index==self.get_size()-1: #removing from the end
            cur=self[self.get_size()-2] #get the second to last nod3 
            
            cur.next=None #point to none
            
       # else: #remove form middle
```

Comment: I assume you are going to add a function to this class, and not just use `__getitem__`.  That would be horribly inefficient, since you have to traverse the entire list for each item.  Your function would loop through the list, and if `cur.next.val` is your guy, you'll set `cur.next` to `cur.next.next`.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

With the method `self.__getitem__` you can obtain the `index-1` node, then you can `current_node.next = current_node.next.next`, in other words set the next node of the `current_node` as the next node of it's next node.